# Knockout -how to transfer multiselect listbox items(any orde selected items) to another listbox using Knockout?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I have Two multiselect list view (dropdownList multiple) and when the user selected one option in the first list, automatically insert/transfer to second multiple list (dropdownList) and also remove that option from the first multiselect list.

```
<label>Selectable Services</label>
<select class="span12" id="selectService" data-bind="foreach: groups, value: selectedOption" Multiple="Multiple" height="10">
    <optgroup data-bind="attr: { label: label }, foreach: children">
        <option data-bind="text: label, option: $data"></option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<label>Selected Services</label>
<select class="span12" id="selectedService" multiple="multiple" height="5" data-bind="options: allServices, selectedOptions: selectedServices"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use two observableArrays for available options of both selects. From one .remove(item) and .push(item) to the other. Knockout will track changes. Try an event or click binding. Or put this function in computed observable watching selected items.

You didn't made a sample jsfiddle to help you some more with example.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the same. My JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yfxKV/. The problem is that when I click on Available list, [Object object] is added to the Selected list and the selected item is not removed from the available list.

Comment: That's because `click` binds `$data` as function argument and when you bind it to `select` the `$data` is whole view model, not a single item (so there are no matching items to add/remove). Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/yfxKV/8/ Now every `<option>` has own `click` binding so each array item is passed as an argument.

Comment: There are some missing tags in fiddle. You should check that. Other than this I can't help, I don't have IE.

Comment: I think it's a common problem for JSFiddle. It seems it's not compatible with IE8.